# ifconfig command issue

Tags: centos, ssh, vmware, ifconfig

My goal is to connect to centos6 machine which is sitting on VMware , using putty tool from my windows machine.
To connect with putty as you know I need ip address of my Centos6 machine.
Thats the reason i am trying to run ifconfig command on my centos6 machine.
The output of the command is showing inet6 address but not ipv4 address of my centos6 machine.
The problem with ifconfig command is a new one(today).But my ability to connect to my centos machine through putty is older problem(since yesterday I am trying to through putty but its unresponsive and timedout).I also had [image]the screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have an IP for the device. `Scope Link` for the IPv6 address is local. If it would have an IP accessible, `Scope` would be `Global`.

Read about address scope, [here](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html)

If you can get inside the centos box, try doing `ifup eth0`.